# Width auto is not working when hover

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a web application where I need to do some design tweaks. Please check this one http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/5w3FG/9/

When I hover, it shows the border in gray. What I need is I want to fit the border box to fit the width of the text. I tried to set the width:auto but still its not working, showing the border box to the page width size.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Set `text-preview` to inline-block:

```
#text-preview {
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1; /* if you need IE7 support */
}
```

Inline-block will cause the element to render as if inline rather than occupying all of the available horizontal space, but will lets you set inner dimensions and padding as a block element would.

Note that IE7 doesn't support inline-block unless you force the `hasLayout` property.  The easiest way to do that is with `zoom:1;`.

Answer (score 0):

`width:auto` on a `div` translates to `width:100%` because a `div` is a block level element.

If you want to have it size to the text you'll need to either use a more appropriate inline tag like a `span` or depending on the semantic meaning of the data, a definition list (`dl`).

You can also change the `display` property of your wrapper `div` to be `inline` or `inline-block` but that is not semantically correct.